# How to debug Dependency Injection Bugs in Extbase?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm building an extension in Extbase (latest version, latest typo3) and am having repositories injected into my models.

This simply does not work. No errors, no clues, nothing. The inject* Method simply does not get called. The exact same Injection works in the controller.

Is it possible to inject Repositories into models in Extbase? In general, injection to models is possible since 1.4.

How can I debug this? Where do I have to look?

Comment: Are you trying to inject a repository from a different extension? The loading order of the extensions will have an effect on whether the repository is available or not..

Answer (score 3):

This is a common misconception:

Not every class you use in TYPO3 CMS uses dependency injection by default - and it's a good thing.

What is true, is that every object that has been instantiated by the ObjectManager can benefit from it.

In short: if you `new Thing()` some object, it won't benefit from dependency injection. If you use the `ObjectManager` to get an instance of something, the whole dependency injection gallore will rain down on your new instance:

- constructor injection [Example: [How can I use an injected object in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915782/how-can-i-use-an-injected-object-in-the-constructor])
- annotations are read and field injections are done
- setter injection was done in the past (Remark: I think it's deprecated)
- public method (if existent) `initializeObject` is called

Note that injected objects are being instantiated by the objectManager as well-so recursion is possible if injected `ServiceA` needs an injected `ServiceB`.

Singletons are possible as well if you implement the marker interface `SingletonInterface`.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection only works if you get an instance of the object via the `ObjectManager`. If you are using the good ol'

```
t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_yourextension_domain_model_thing')
```

inject* methods are not being called.

There is a german [blog entry](http://www.networkteam.com/blog/post/dependency-injection-in-extbase.html) explaining how it works.

Comment: I've read the german blog entry (as I am from germany, but I found stackoverflow answers more competent). 

However, I don't get your answer. I'm not using the good ol' one, but only the recommended way. Can you explain in a little more detail why you think it's not working?

Comment: You must not use t3lib_div::makeInstance()! Get an instance of the object manager and ask him for the object.

Comment: Ok, I have to answer the question myself and it's kind of dumb ^^

I was using FLOW3 before and was coming to extbase. In flow3, it's enough to use the 'new' Operator to create instances, extbase requires the object manager - which works like a charm.