# How can I use an injected object in the constructor?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a service class in my Extbase extension and want to use the ObjectManager to create an instance of an object in the constructor.

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
 * @inject
 */
protected $objectManager;

public function __construct() {
    $this->standaloneView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView');
    $this->standaloneView->setFormat('html');
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't fails with an error `Call to a member function get() on null` because the injected class doesn't seem to be available in the constructor. How can I use an injected class in the constructur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this, I can use so-called constructor injection. The ObjectManagerInterface is defined as an argument of the constructor and then automatically injected by Extbase:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
 */
protected $objectManager;

public function __construct(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager) {
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->standaloneView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView');
    $this->standaloneView->setFormat('html');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to lorenz answer, you could use the lifecycle-method `initializeObject()`. It will be called after dependency injection has been done.

Comment: I wouldnt. That's what constructors are there for-set things up.

Comment: Another philosophy is this: The constructor should only used for construction once, when the object is created and then never again. Not even if it is thawn from a database or cache or something. Lifecycle methods are called in any case. But I guess both ways will work in TYPO3, and that won't change soon, so this is more of a theoretical thing.

Comment: That raises an immediate question: How often do you serialize Service Objects or Controllers? - The model should be anemic so where would this theoretical thing happen in the current state?

Comment: In TYPO3 it would not happen, as far as I know, because most objects only live for the time of one request. But in other languages with a different execution model (e.g. Java), this might very well happen: If the controller/service/whatever is not needed, it can be frozen and put into some cache, and be thawn once it is needed again. Thus this is rather theoretical for TYPO3.

Comment: Exactly-that's why I'm asking. The label is TYPO3, so why mix concerns that dont matter in?